# rxSwift extension for converting Single<[Element]> to Observable<Element>

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, observable, rx-swift

I'm having a real hard time trying to create an extension that converts a Single array to an Observable. So for example I have a `Single<[Address]>` and I want to convert it to an `Observable<Address>`.

The code I have to write each time I want to do this is

```
mySingleVariable.asObservable().flatMap({ addresses in Observable.from(addresses) })
```

This operation is very common and the code is quite verbose. My attempt to create an extension looks like the following

```
extension PrimitiveSequence where Trait == SingleTrait {
    func flatObservable<R: Collection>() -> Observable<R.Element> {
        return asObservable().flatMap({ element in Observable.from(element) })
    }
}
```

The code above unfortunately does not work. The error I get is "Generic parameter 'R' is not used in function signature". This is because the function returns `Observable<R.Element>`. If it were to return `Observable<R>`, the error would go away, but it's not the result I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension PrimitiveSequence where Trait == SingleTrait, Element: Sequence {

    func flatObservable<R>() -> Observable<R> where R == Element.Element {
        return asObservable().flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. Do you have any suggestions about how I should name this function? Do you find "flatObservable" appropriate?

Comment: I wouldn't use this function personally. You say in your question that this is "very common" in your code, but I almost never use anything like it. Years of development with Rx and I've maybe used `.from` a couple times total.